# how to control raspberry pi 3 using internet and vnc?

Tags: raspbian

```
<11> 2017-06-14T11:44:03.185Z raspberrypi vncviewer[13491]: vncviewer: unable to open display ""
<11> 2017-06-14T11:44:03.185Z raspberrypi vncviewer[13491]: TXMsgBox: unable to open display ""
<11> 2017-06-14T11:44:03.185Z raspberrypi vncviewer[13491]: TXMsgBox: unable to open display ""
```

error shown on the terminal

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide more information? As it stands your question is rather terse, and it is nigh impossible to know where the problem lies. The more information that you provide, the easier it will be for someone to answer. Also, can you edit your question and add code formatting to your error, using the code formatting buitton in the editor..? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the Desktop to control the Raspberry Pi (console mode), you can use ssh.
You need to redirect the 22 port to the raspberry Pi local IP address.